# Using VBA to set the parameters of a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So I have a query, as shown below, which runs on a parameter.

I was wondering if there is a way to use VBA to set the query parameters.  I currently have about 40 queries all exactly the same except for the product ID, and as such I have 40 reports as well...  if i have the one query, I will still have to write out the code for the productid in the VBA, but i can use one report instead of that many.

Life would be much easier with just one query and one report and have the VBA set the parameters, as the user does not know the product ID

```
SELECT TblTotalSale.ProductID, TblProduct.Description, TblTotalSale.Size, TblTotalSale.SalePrice, TblTotalSale.Day
FROM TblProduct INNER JOIN TblTotalSale ON TblProduct.ProductID = TblTotalSale.ProductID
WHERE (((TblTotalSale.ProductID)=[]));
```

The VBA

```
Private Sub IPA_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "RptProduct", acViewReport, , [TblTotalSale.ProductID="5"]

End Sub
```

I have also tried tblTotalSale.ProductID = "5"
I know I am using SQL where I should be using VBA...

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not include a parameter for the sql statement for reports and forms. Use the Where argument of the OpenForm or OpenReport method of the DoCmd object.

[DoCmd.OpenReport Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: so remove the where in the SQL and in the VBA write

    DoCmd.OpenReport "RptProduct", acViewReport, , TblTotalSale.ProductID=5

?

Comment: With quotes `"TblTotalSale.ProductID=5"` or for text, `"AText='ABC'"`